# com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type as an element

Tags: java, xml, sqlite

I have created a database using sqlite and Java, and I want to export the data i successfully inserted into that database named "BazaDeDate" into XML File, but it doesn't work, it gives me this error. Here is the code:

```
public class ExportXML {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
    {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"); 
        Connection conexiune=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:BazaDeDate.db");
        Statement comanda=conexiune.createStatement(); 

        ResultSet rs=comanda.executeQuery("SELECT* FROM AvionPasageri");


        JAXBContext context=JAXBContext.newInstance(AvionPasageri.class);

        Marshaller marshaller=context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,true); 

        while(rs.next())
        {
            String serie=rs.getString("serie");
            float tonaj=rs.getFloat("tonaj");
            String marca=rs.getString("marca");
            float capacitate=rs.getFloat("capacitate");
            String cnp=rs.getString("cnp");
            List<String>listaCnp=new Vector<>(); 
            listaCnp.add(cnp); 

            AvionPasageri ap=new AvionPasageri(serie, tonaj, marca, capacitate,listaCnp);

            File f=new File("AvionPasageri.xml"); 
            marshaller.marshal(ap,f);

        }



    }
}
```

AvionPasageri is my class used to create the objects I inserted into the database, and now I want to export into XML.

serie, tonaj, marca, capacitate, cnp are used to refer to class AvionPasageri's attributes.

Please help me to figure out what's wrong.

These are the errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "pachetClase.AvionPasageri" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(Unknown Source)
    at pachetExportXML.ExportXML.main(ExportXML.java:44)
Caused by: com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "pachetClase.AvionPasageri" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

EDIT: Class AvionPasageri, derived from abstract class Avion looks like this:

```
public class AvionPasageri extends Avion implements Cloneable {

    private float nrLocuri;
    private List<String>cnpPasageri=new Vector<String>();

    public AvionPasageri(String serie, float tonaj, String marca, float nrLocuri, List<String>cnpPasageri) throws Exception
    {
        super(serie, tonaj, marca);
        if(tonaj<0)
            throw new Exception("Tonaj negativ!");

        this.setNrLocuri(nrLocuri);
        this.setCnpPasageri(cnpPasageri);

    }

    //properties(get&set for attributes) are here

    @Override
    public float getCapacitate() {...} //abstract method inherited

    @Override
    public AvionPasageri clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {..}

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {...}

    @Override
    public String toString() {...}

}
```

I put some "..." in the body of some methods to make the code shorter.

Comment: The error message says there is no `@XmlRootElement` annotation in your `AvionPasageri` class. Have you added any JAXB annotations to this class? How does it look like?

Comment: I added the code of AvionPasageri class above.@BalázsNemes

Answer (score 2):

As it is mentioned you can include the @XmlRootElement at the beginning of the class. But in my case the classes were autogenerated so it was not a solution for me. If you want to marshall the object without the label just include the QName and generate the object without the @XmlRootElement:

```
        // Here include your package and your class
        QName qName = new QName("com.atos.nextcare.orm", "ORMO01CONTENT");
        JAXBElement<ORMO01CONTENT> root = new JAXBElement<>(qName, ORMO01CONTENT.class, request.getORMO01());

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal(root, sw);
```

I follow the example given [here](https://www.codenotfound.com/jaxb-marshal-element-missing-xmlrootelement-annotation.html)

Comment: Please follow the link given... It's explained clearly there.

Answer (score 0):

To get JAXB work you have to provide a mapping between your classes and the desired XML elements. This mapping is provided in form of annotations added to your classes which represents XML elements. You can find tutorials on the web about how to do it:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/

Also if you have an xsd schema for your desired xml, then JAXB can generate you the necessary classes.